# Looking for a short story about a robot evolving to have supernatural powers

Tags: story-identification, robots

I'm looking for a short story from about 50 years ago about a robot who escapes after being slated to be melted down and discovers while in hiding that it has evolved to have some supernatural powers.

Comment: What about the [Iron Giant?](http://static1.squarespace.com/static/51b3dc8ee4b051b96ceb10de/t/51fd7424e4b0b77d0572b7c0/1375564839151/Iron+Giant+Superman+art.png) :P

Comment: duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/77308/what-story-has-a-robot-that-gains-psychic-power-after-direct-exposure-to-hypersp

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would surmise that this is the story ***"All the Traps of Earth"*** (1962) by Clifford D. Simak.

[image]

The main character is an android by the name of Richard Daniel, who has been serving an aristocratic family for over half a millennium, until the last of their line passes away.  He is not threatened with destruction per se, but rather with being memory-wiped and reprogrammed.  He becomes a fugitive and, while on the lam, discovers that he has developed telekinesis, allowing him to repair technology and living systems using only his thoughts.

> He had abilities that Man had never won or developed or achieved, whichever it might be. He was a certain step ahead of not only other robots, but of Man as well. He had a thing, or the beginning of a thing, that Man had sought and studied and had tried to grasp for centuries and had failed.
>
> A solemn and a deadly thought: was it possible that it was the robots, after all, for whom this great heritage had been meant? Would it be the robots who would achieve the **paranormal powers** that Man had sought so long, while Man, perforce, must remain content with the materialistic and the merely scientific? Was he, Richard Daniel, perhaps, only the first of many?

Comment: Yes, this is IT.  -Thanks, Chevy.